# How to format TimeSpan in wpf (DataGrid)?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, format, timestamp

I had a TimeSpan saved into SqlCe in ticks, and when i load the data in a DataGrid i want to format this value in HH:MM:SS. I try it with this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding tiempo, StringFormat={}{0:hh':'mm':'ss}, TargetNullValue=' --- '}"  Width="80" Header="Tiempo"/>
```

But the DataGrid shows 'hh:mm:ss' instead of the value.

i try also try it with other patterns like  `StringFormat="hh\:mm\:ss"`

Any idea?

Thanks! and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Not sure if you can use `String.Format` inside your binding. But you can easily achieve this by using a `ValueConverter`. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

Comment: @programmer93 That's the [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) property, not the String.Format method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem! in database i was storing "tiempo" like bigint, so i changed it to nvarchar and making a few fixes it works. 
thanks for all!

Answer (score 5):

You could write it like this with double backslashes:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding tiempo, StringFormat=hh\\:mm\\:ss}"/>
```

or like this with single backslashes:

```
<DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="tiempo" StringFormat="hh\:mm\:ss"/>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

although that is already the default formatting, so

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding tiempo}"/>
```

should also be ok.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7627604/1136211) for a few more examples.

Comment: mm the same result, the datagrid shows hh:mm:ss but not the formatted value

Comment: I even tried it with a DataGridTextColumn and it works for me. Could you show the declaration of the `tiempo` property?